# Using R spatial to calculate the nearest weather stations to sample plots using coordinates

Tags: r, visualization, distance, latitude-longitude, nearest-neighbor

I have 2 dataset, one contains information on 18 sites (site_name, lat and long) and the second contains 81 weather stations data (met_name, lat and long). i want to calculate the distance between each sites and the weather stations in other to get the nearest weather stations. However, i want it in a visual form so that i can see the next weather station close to the sites incase the nearest one does not have a complete information that i need.

I have tried this code i found in one of the thread here but it is not working well for me. I will also like to point out that i converted the data from data.frame to vector which was stressful.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

CompID<-c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12", 
      "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A18")
sitexy<- matrix(c(-28.4,-28.7,-28.6,-28.5,-28.4,-28.7,-28.2,-28.3,-28.9,-28.6,-28.5,-28.5,-28.7,
             -28.7,-28.7,-28.5,-28.5,-28.5,32.2,32.1,32.2,32.2,32.2,32.0,32.3,32.2,31.9,32.2,32.2,
              32.2,32.1,32.1,32.1,32.1,32.1,32.1), ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
MetID<-c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", "M13", "M14", 
         "M15","M16", "M17", "M18", "M19", "M20", "M21", "M22", "M23", "M24", "M25", "M26", "M27", 
         "M28", "M29", "M30", "M31","M32", "M33", "M34", "M35", "M36", "M37", "M38", "M39", "M40", 
          "M41", "M42","M43", "M44", "M45", "M46", "M47","M48", "M49", "M50", "M51", "M52", "M53", 
         "M54", "M55", "M56", "M57","M58", "M59", "M60", "M61", "M62", "M63", "M64","M65", "M66", 
         "M67", "M68", "M69", "M70", "M71","M72", "M73", "M74", "M75", "M76", "M77", "M78", "M79", 
         "M80", "M81")

metxy<-matrix(c(-28.74, -28.44, -28.20, -28.72, -28.45, -31.06, -30.75, -30.86, -30.15, -30.40, 
               -29.79,
            -29.94, -29.54, -29.63, -29.65, -29.71, -29.77, -29.61, -29.60, -29.26, -29.22, -30.50,
            -29.08, -29.16, -28.69, -28.58, -29.01, -28.95, -28.85, -28.74, -28.38, -28.36, -28.31,
            28.44, -28.20, -27.78, -27.41, -27.39, -27.57, -27.31, -27.55, -27.13, -27.39, -29.06,
            -29.05, -29.25, -29.04, -29.20, -29.32, -29.26, -29.64, -26.85, -28.58, -28.50, -26.94,
            -27.01, -27.03, -29.94, -29.83, -30.13, -29.57, -29.65, -30.21, -28.60, -28.89, -28.35,
            -28.22, 28.72, 28.90, 28.90, 29.02, 27.42, 28.58, 28.50, 27.63, 28.45, 27.40,28.45,28.60, 
             28.35, 28.22, 32.09, 32.18, 32.41, 31.88, 32.22, 30.22, 30.26, 30.34, 30.07, 
            30.69, 29.35, 29.96, 30.27, 30.40, 30.40, 31.05, 31.06, 31.12, 31.13, 29.52, 30.00, 
            29.39, 30.60, 31.40, 28.95, 29.75, 29.86, 31.71, 31.85, 32.09, 29.39, 31.21, 31.42, 
            32.18, 32.41, 30.80, 31.59, 32.18, 30.82, 30.71, 30.51, 30.91, 30.83, 30.82, 30.89, 
            30.33, 30.52, 30.67, 30.58, 30.50, 30.51, 30.46, 31.33, 31.34, 30.83, 30.79, 30.61, 
            29.91, 30.31, 29.89, 30.27, 29.97, 30.08, 32.18, 31.83, 32.25, 32.36, 31.88, 31.31, 
            31.43, 31.60, 32.20, 31.33, 31.34, 32.02, 32.22, 31.58, 32.28, 32.18, 32.25, 32.36), ncol 
            = 2, byrow = TRUE)


d<-pointDistance(sitexy, metxy, lonlat = TRUE)
r<-apply(d, 1, which.min)
r
p<-data.frame(site=CompID, Met=MetID [r])
p

plot(rbind(metxy, sitexy), ylim=c(0,45), xlab='longitude', ylab='latitude')
points(metxy, col="red", pch=20, cex=2)
points(sitexy, col="blue", pch=20, cex=2)
text(sitexy, CompID, pos=1)
text(metxy, MetID, pos=1)
for(i in 1:nrow(subxy)) {
arrows(subxy[i,1], subxy[i,2], blockxy[r[i], 1], blockxy[r[i],2])}
```

[Here is the output i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ZVF.png)

Comment: Are #17 and #34 in metxy correct?

Comment: From the output i got initially, i saw the outliers too. They are available data given to me and i am not sure if they are correct or there is a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if these two coordinates are correct. They appear as outliers (errors?) on your plot.

```
metxy
        [,1]   [,2]
[15,] -28.85 -28.74
[16,] -28.38 -28.36
[17,] -28.31  28.44 # <--- this one
[18,] -28.20 -27.78
[19,] -27.41 -27.39

[33,] -28.89 -28.35
[34,] -28.22  28.72 # <--- and this one.
[35,]  28.90  28.90
```

Anyway, it looks like there are two (or 3?) distinct regions, each containing 9 sites. You can visualise this with:

```
plot(metxy)
```

Region 1 contains 34 weather stations and region 2 contains 47. To better visualize the distances, you could either split the data by region, or use `xlim` and `ylim` to zoom in to the particular coordinates of interest.

```
op <- par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), mfrow=c(1,2))

plot(rbind(metxy, sitexy), xlab='longitude', ylab='latitude', las=1, 
        xlim=c(-27.75, -29.25), ylim=c(-27.75, -29.25))

grid()
points(metxy, col="red", pch=20)
points(sitexy, col="blue", pch=20)
text(sitexy, CompID, pos=1, cex=0.7, col="blue")
text(metxy, MetID, pos=1, cex=0.6, col="red")
legend("topleft", legend=c("Weather station", "Research site"), pch=20, col=c("red","blue"), title="Region 1", bty="n")


for(i in seq_along(r)) {
  arrows(sitexy[i,1], sitexy[i,2], metxy[r[i], 1], metxy[r[i],2], length=0.1)
}

plot(rbind(metxy, sitexy), xlab='longitude', ylab='latitude', las=1, 
     xlim=c(31.5, 32.5), ylim=c(31.5, 32.5), yaxt="n")
#etc....
...
par(op)
```

[image]

Site A1 and A3 appear to have the same location and this is confirmed by inspecting the data, as do A6 and A9. The overlapping text is a small problem, but I am not familiar with any base functions that can alleviate this like the ggrepel package.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try this and see how well it works.